# Vue form validation

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning `Vue` and I would like an opinion to improve the form validation that I have implemented. This is my component:

```
<template>
    <section class="p-0 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Right START -->
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-9 mx-auto my-5 position-relative">
            <!-- Shape Decoration START -->
            <!-- Shape 1 -->

            <!-- Shape Decoration END -->
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div
                class="
                    col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-5
                    text-start
                    mx-auto
                    d-flex
                    align-items-center
                "
                >
                <div class="w-100">
                    <h3>Sign up for your account!</h3>
                    <p>
                    Join us today! Create your account easily with less
                    information.
                    </p>
                    <!-- Form START -->
                    <form class="mt-4" @submit.prevent="submit">
                    <!-- Email -->
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input
                        v-model="data.name"
                        v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': emailFailure }"
                        required
                        type="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="email"
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="E-mail"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ emailFailureText }}
                        </div>
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"
                        >We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small
                        >
                    </div>
                    <!-- Username -->
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="email">Username</label>
                        <input
                        v-model="data.username"
                        v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': usernameFailure }"
                        required
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="username"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ usernameFailureText }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                        <input
                        v-model="data.password"
                        v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': passwordFailure }"
                        required
                        type="password"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="password"
                        placeholder="*********"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ passwordFailureText }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="password2"
                        >Confirm Password</label
                        >
                        <input
                        v-model="data.password2"
                        v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': password2Failure }"
                        type="password"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="password2"
                        placeholder="*********"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ password2FailureText }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- Form END -->
                    <div class="bg-dark-overlay-dotted py-2 my-4"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Right END -->
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </template>

    <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent, reactive, ref } from "vue";
    import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

    export default defineComponent({
    name: "Register",
    setup(props) {
        const data = reactive({
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        password2: "",
        });
        const router = useRouter();

        const emailFailure = ref(false);
        const emailFailureText = ref("");
        const usernameFailure = ref(false);
        const usernameFailureText = ref("");
        const passwordFailure = ref(false);
        const passwordFailureText = ref("");
        const password2Failure = ref(false);
        const password2FailureText = ref("");

        const submit = async () => {
        emailFailure.value = false;
        emailFailureText.value = "";
        usernameFailure.value = false;
        usernameFailureText.value = "";
        passwordFailure.value = false;
        passwordFailureText.value = "";
        password2Failure.value = false;
        password2FailureText.value = "";

        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/auth/register`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
            const errors = await res.json();
            emailFailure.value = true;
            emailFailureText.value = "the email is invalid";
        }

        /*
        if (res.text === 200) {
            await router.push("/login");
        }*/
        };

        return {
        data,
        emailFailure,
        emailFailureText,
        submit,
        };
    },
    });
</script>
```

what I did so far is define inside the method `setup`, a `data` variable which will handle all the values that the user fill in the form. These values are passed to my `API` using the `fetch` method which is called in the `submit` function.

When the `API` call is completed, I check if the `response` was successfull or not by checking the `ok` property. If the response is unsuccessful I valorize all the property of each field manually to display the error on the proper field.

The code above just have the `emailFailure` implementation, and this is actually working fine, but my concern is about all the fields. Suppose that I have 20 fields, should I have create 20 property which handle the error, and other 20 which handle the error message?

There is a way to handle multiple fields without create all those properties?

Also, the `API` response return an array of objects like this:

```
[{
    location: "body",
    msg: "invalid email",
    param: "email",
    value: ""
}, {
    location: "body",
    msg: "Password must be at least 8 characters",
    param: "password",
    value: ""
}]
```

as you can see I have the `param` field which is equal to the input name defined in the `Vue` component.